# How do I get value by other column max value for particular user in SQL

Tags: sql

I have next table:

```
(AUTO_INCREMENT)
     |
     V
survey_id   | user_id| tries |  results
------------|--------|---------------
    1       |   10   |  1    |   A
    2       |   10   |  2    |   B
    3       |   11   |  1    |   C
    4       |   10   |  3    |   D
    5       |   11   |  2    |   E
```

I have, for example, `user_id = 10` and I want to get the value from the `result` row where tries value has the max result for this user, in this case it is going to be `D` result.

How could I do this query in `SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with simple subquery

```
select * from tbl t
where user_id = '10'
  and tries = (select max(tries) from tbl ti where t.user_id = ti.user_id )
```